# iText Java - Scaling pages of different sizes. Returns an error with some PDFs

Tags: java, itext

I need your help.

I'm using your code to scale the pages in a PDF, leaving them the same size and the content fits within A4.

The code runs and serves the purpose, but compiling with a specific PDF threw this exception.

> **The CMap com/itextpdf/io/font/cmap/UniJIS-UTF16-H was not found.**

```
public byte[] gerarPDFViaGet() throws IOException {
    
            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    
            com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument mergedPdf = new com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument(
                    new com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter(outputStream) );
    
            com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.Rectangle pageSize = com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.PageSize.A4;
            com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.Rectangle pageBodySize = pageSize.clone()
                    .applyMargins(10, 10, 10, 10, false);
    
            InputStream resource = new FileInputStream("document_78.pdf");
            com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader pdfReader = new com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader(resource);
            com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument pdfDocument = new com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument(pdfReader);
    
            pdfDocument.copyPagesTo(1, pdfDocument.getNumberOfPages(), mergedPdf, new PdfPageFormCopier());
            scale(mergedPdf, pageSize, pageBodySize);
    
            mergedPdf.close();
    
            return outputStream.toByteArray();
    
        }
```

Scale.

```
void scale(com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument pdfDocument, com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.Rectangle pageSize,
                   com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.Rectangle pageBodySize) {
    
            for (int i = 1; i <= pdfDocument.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
                com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfPage page = pdfDocument.getPage(i);
    
                // ROTACAO E ORIENTACAO DAS PAGINAS
                if( page.getPageSizeWithRotation().getWidth() > page.getPageSizeWithRotation().getHeight() )
                    pdfDocument.getPage(i).put(com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfName.Rotate,PORTRAIT);
    
                if ( page.getRotation() == 90 )
                    pdfDocument.getPage(i).put(com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfName.Rotate,PORTRAIT);
    
                MarginFinder marginFinder = new MarginFinder();
                com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.canvas.parser.PdfCanvasProcessor pdfCanvasProcessor = new com.itextpdf.kernel
                        .pdf.canvas.parser.PdfCanvasProcessor(marginFinder);
                pdfCanvasProcessor.processPageContent(page);
                com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.Rectangle boundingBox = marginFinder.getBoundingBox();
                if (boundingBox == null || boundingBox.getWidth() == 0 || boundingBox.getHeight() == 0) {
                    System.err.printf("Não é possível dimensionar o conteúdo da página %d com a caixa delimitadora %s\n",
                            i , boundingBox);
                    continue;
                } else {
    
                    List<Double> retornoScales = calcularFatorScale(pageBodySize,boundingBox);
                    double scale = retornoScales.get(0);
                    double xDiff = retornoScales.get(1);
                    double yDiff = retornoScales.get(2);
    
                    if( scale > 0.5 ){
    
                            com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.AffineTransform transform = com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.AffineTransform
                                    .getTranslateInstance(pageBodySize.getLeft() + xDiff, pageBodySize.getBottom() + yDiff);
                            transform.scale(scale, scale);
                            transform.translate(-boundingBox.getLeft(), -boundingBox.getBottom());
                            new com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.canvas.PdfCanvas(page.newContentStreamBefore(), page.getResources(), pdfDocument)
                                    .concatMatrix(transform);
                    }
                }
                page.setMediaBox(pageSize);
                page.setCropBox(pageSize);
            }
        }
```

FatorScale.

```
public List<Double> calcularFatorScale(com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.Rectangle pageBodySize,
                                               com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.Rectangle boundingBox){
    
            List<Double> retornoScales = new ArrayList<>();
            double scale = 0, xDiff= 0, yDiff = 0;
    
            double xScale = pageBodySize.getWidth()/boundingBox.getWidth();
            double yScale = pageBodySize.getHeight()/boundingBox.getHeight();
            if (xScale < yScale) {
                yDiff = boundingBox.getHeight() * (yScale / xScale - 1) / 2;
                scale = xScale;
            } else {
                xDiff = boundingBox.getWidth() * (xScale / yScale - 1) / 2;
                scale = yScale;
            }
    
            retornoScales.add(scale);
            retornoScales.add(xDiff);
            retornoScales.add(yDiff);
    
            return retornoScales;
        }
```

Some example PDFs return what you expect. But others return the exception:
**CMap com/itextpdf/io/font/cmap/UniJIS-UTF16-H was not found.**

Two example PDFs for entry. One of them returns this exception;

Comment: Try add `IText Asian Fonts` jar. ( https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/font-asian )

Comment: I added the dependency, but it keeps returning the error.    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
   <artifactId>font-asian</artifactId>
   <version>7.2.5</version>

Comment: What is your itext version ?

Comment: <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
   <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
   <version>5.5.13.3</version>

Comment: Could it be from iText.KERNEL, since I'm using it?

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itext-asian/5.2.0

Comment: open `https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itextpdf/5.5.13.3`, find       `jar` link, download (`itextpdf-5.5.13.3.jar`) , unzip `itextpdf-5.5.13.3.jar`, then try to find `UniJIS-UTF16-H.*`, you can not find it. But you can find it from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itext-asian/5.2.0.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer.

ok, I didn't find it in itextpdf-5.5.13.3.jar, but I found it in itext-asian-5.2.2.jar.
And now what do I do ?

Comment: add `<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itext-asian</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.0</version>
</dependency>`

Comment: I added dependency itext-asian, but it keeps returning the same error.
The CMap com/itextpdf/io/font/cmap/UniJIS-UTF16-H was not found.

I don't understand why this is happening, since the PDF contains 20 pages in the Portuguese language.

Comment: I changed the version of iTextpdf. From 5.5.13.3 to suite 7.2.5, i.e. I removed all dependencies from previous iTextpdf and left only suite 7.2.5., so it worked.   

  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
   <artifactId>itext7-core</artifactId>
   <version>7.2.5</version>
   <type>pom</type>
  </dependency>